# How to do Invert Selection in Sublime text 4?

Tags: selection, sublimetext, sublimetext4

In previous version (ST3) of Sublime Text, there was invert selection in Selection menu. With which you could simple select the text you desired to keep, invert the selection and delete.

Seems it's removed in current version. How to perform same action?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

while Selection > invert selection menu was removed in ST4, it is still available through command invert_selection. So one can use it by binding that command to some key combination. Here is my setup:

I used ctrl+i and ctrl+s multiple combination keys, which actually easier to remember. (**i**nvert **s**election)so if you use windows, go to Key Bindings by pressing ctrl+shift+P and then type Key Bindings. You will have your key bindings window open in new sublime text window, to the pane that's on right hand side (User defined key bindings) you can insert following:
Make sure you insert it inside parent curly braces

```
{
    {..some other key bindings..},
    { "keys": ["ctrl+i", "ctrl+s"], "command": "invert_selection" }
}
```

Comment: In Sublime Text 4, the outer curly brackets were not needed. Just add this inside the square brackets on the right pane: { "keys": ["ctrl+i", "ctrl+s"], "command": "invert_selection" }

Answer (score 3):

If you want to put it back in the menu, you can create a file called **Main.sublime-menu** with the content:

```
[
    {
        "caption": "Selection",
        "mnemonic": "S",
        "id": "selection",
        "children":
        [
            { "command": "invert_selection", "caption": "Invert Selection", "mnemonic": "i" },
        ]
    }
]
```

Save the file in **%APPDATA%\Sublime Text\Packages\User** folder (in Sublime Text, you can click `Preferences -> Browse Packages` to open the User folder)